# How to get redirect location with python when it only shows when click in browser

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to download some audio clips from http://www.pingshu8.com/down_121010.html

By using scrapy I get the real file linkage by:

```
from urllib.parse import unquote
fetch('http://www.pingshu8.com/down_121008.html')
downurl=response.xpath('//script/text()').extract()[0]
downurl=unquote(unquote(downurl))
downurl1=response.urljoin(re.search('bzmtv_Inc/download.asp\?fid=\d+&t=\d+',downurl).group())
```

but when I use

```
fetch(downurl1)
```

I got 200 status instead of 301 redirect to right URL.

I found I can only get right result when I click the download button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The site checks for both **Referer** and **User-Agent**:

```
import re
from urllib import unquote
from scrapy.http import Request

initial_url = 'http://www.pingshu8.com/down_121008.html'
fetch(initial_url)
downurl = unquote(unquote(response.xpath('//script/text()').extract()[0]))
downurl = response.urljoin(re.search('bzmtv_Inc/download.asp\?fid=\d+&t=\d+', downurl).group())

# if you request without these required headers (User-Agent and Referer) no content is returned
r = Request(downurl)
fetch(r)
print response.body

# but if you request with those headers, it will return content
request_with_headers = Request(
      downurl,
      headers = {
        'Referer': initial_url,
        'User-Agent':'Mozilla/4.6 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.326.109 Safari/507.23',
      },
      meta = {
        'dont_redirect': True,
        'handle_httpstatus_list': [301,302],
      }
)
fetch(request_with_headers)
print response.headers.get('Location')
```

**Output from example with headers:**

```
>>> print response.headers.get('Location')
https://down01.pingshu8.com:8011/2/ys/儿童文学60年经典回放(16集)/儿童文学60年经典回放_01.mp3?t=ztmu1924596a0610b630ddd21a54fda258fa0&m=5C9208AE
```